# Find two generators for a lattice (2D)

Tags: group-theory, geometry, vectors, integer-lattices

I want to solve this problem, given $n$ vectors $v_1, v_2, ..., v_n$ in two dimensions, find two vectors that spans the same lattice spanned by $v_1, v_2, ..., v_n$.

For instance, if $n = 3$ and $v_1 = (494, -606), v_2 = (-346, -821), v_3 = (-592, -174)$. We can span the same lattice using the following two vectors: $(0, 1), (2, 0)$. That is, the sets of points generated by **integer** linear combinations of $[v_1, v_2, v_n]$ and $[(0, 1), (2, 0)]$ are the same.

All values should be integers.

Comment: you do not give your background. Do you know what  a Gram matrix is?

Comment: @WillJagy no idea, I just found a programming problem where I need (guess I need) this.

Comment: well, lattice reduction is easy in dimension 2, it is Gauss reduction for positive (integer coefficient) binary quadratic forms. I guess what is missing for you is to get a reduced basis for $n-1$ vectors, check whether $v_n$ is already in that lattice, if not make a reduced basis for the revised lattice. Let me do your 3 point case an d see how it goes.

Comment: How do you know the reduced basis for your lattice?????

Comment: @WillJagy I don't want a reduced basis. I want any generator for my lattice, and then I will apply Gauss reduction. If I can get a reduced basis at first, then that will be ok too.

Comment: Trying again: how do you know that your two lattices are the same???

Comment: @WillJagy for my sample?

Comment: yes,............................

Comment: @WillJagy I used LatticeReduce command in Mathematica (https://bit.ly/2uG6LQc) and I assumed that two vectors spans the same lattice :)

Comment: I'm a bit curious now. Your best bet is to read wolfram's documentation. Lattice reduction is a mature subject, and there will be items you will be able to read. Meanwhile, I will write a fairly basic thing to do what I said, get a basis for "so far," then update the basis when a new vector is added that is not already covered. No reason I would  be able to finish  that today.

Comment: @WillJagy The documentation says they are using LLL for LatticeReduce command. I think that algorithm can work: start with two vectors and then add the remaining ones one by one modifying the current two generators.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see: If you can use Mathematica, all you need to do is this: start with LatticeReduce[v1,v2] Retrieve that pair of new vectors, call them w2,x2.

Next, call Lattice Reduce[ w2,x2, v3]. Call the new pair of vectors w3,x3.

Next, call Lattice Reduce[ w3,x3, v4]. Call the new pair of vectors w4,x4.

Next, call Lattice Reduce[ w4,x4, v5]. Call the new pair of vectors w5,x5.

Comment: Can we obtain some pseudocode for LatticeReduce[{a, b, c}]? When we have only two vectors we can apply Gauss reduction algorithm, what about three vectors?

Comment: @lcastillov there will be plenty of sources on LLL written for people with your background. Look up with google and download a few items that seem close to the way you think about things.

Comment: I will check that. However, a smaller (simpler) implementation (idea) for this particular case would be nice.

Comment: @lcastillov this course starts pretty basic: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp14/cse206A-a/index.html

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out.